# Recreate entity singleton

Tags: entity, code-first, dbcontext

I'm using Entity Framework's Database First approach. I would like to have multiple companies in one database and for that I would like to be able to override table name by adding a prefix in front of it (i.e. Company1$Users, Company2$Users) when creating DBContext. It all works fine the first time until I change the company. It seems that DBContext caches entities and it does not fire OnModelCreating next time when I create the context. I have been searching for a solution almost everywhere but cannot seem to find any. Am I the only one having this issue? Is it actually possible? Can someone please help me with this?

The code to recreate the issue is below:

```
public class User 
{ 
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string Username { get; set; } 
}

public class EntityMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public String CompanyId { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public EntityMappingContext(string companyId = null) : base("DB")
    {
        CompanyId = companyId;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable(CompanyId + "$Users");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

To recreate the issue you can run the following:

```
using (var context = new EntityMappingContext("Company1"))
{
    foreach (var user in context.Users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName);
    }
}
using (var context = new EntityMappingContext("Company2"))
{
    foreach (var user in context.Users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName);
    }
}
```

The first and second context queries Company1$Users, eventhough I call the second one with "Company2".

Answer (score 0):

if you go through the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), it says on OnModelCreating method:

> Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created. The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app domain. This caching can be disabled by setting the ModelCaching property on the given ModelBuidler, but this can seriously degrade performance. More control over caching is provided through use of the DbModelBuilder and DbContext classes directly.

Hope it helps